# assigning a value to a variable from an array with a sorting like conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting

in the code below I want to assign random elements of the values array to the values `value1` `value2` I am able to do that, but now I want to make sure that value1 is lower than value 2. you see "tbsp" is smaller than "fl-oz" and cups is smaller than pints etc.

```
function unit(){
   var values = ["tbsp", "fl-oz", "cups", "pint/s", "Quarts" , "Gallon/s"],
   value1 = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
   value2 = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)]
   if(value1 !== value2){
      return [value1, value2]
   }

}
```

I was thinking about doing something like making the array element into an object like `var values = [{item : "tbsp" , rank : 1 }, {item : "fl-oz" , rank : 2}, {item : "cups" ,  rank : 3},`

Comment: `if (value1 > value2) return [value2, value1]`?

Comment: @Bergi that wouldn't work. First of all, `value1` and `value2` are strings. Also that would make the function return `undefined` in several cases rather than an array of two strings.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Oh right, he'd need to do the swapping on the randomly generated indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function unit(){
    var values = ["tbsp", "fl-oz", "cups", "pint/s", "Quarts" , "Gallon/s"],
        value1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (values.length - 1)) + 1,
        value2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * value1);

    return [values[value2], values[value1]];
}
```

First one clamps the range between `1` and `values.length - 1`, second one clamps range between `0` and `value1 - 1`.

Comment: thank's for your answer this looks advance for me btw i did `return [values[value2], values[value1]];` because value 2 was smaller and i wanted the first element of the returned array to be smaller. but it looks like the sorting works so thanks.  im still not sure ho.w this works. I know that Math.random() gets a number from 0-1. i don;t know what you mean by the ' second one clamps range between 0 and value1 - 1.'. thats what the value in in value2 does i don't see `value1 -1`

Comment: @user2537537 So basically `value1` is guaranteed to be a random number between `1` and `5` inclusive since your array length is `6`. `value2` is mathematically calculated to be a random number between `0` and `value1 - 1` inclusive. The reason why is because `Math.random()` never returns `1`, it returns a random floating point value from `0` inclusive to `1` not inclusive. I hope that explanation helps.